# How to specify multiple ranges in excel filter formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to be able to use Excel's filter formula and get only specific columns as a result.

For example, I tried the below formula and failed.

```
=FILTER((A:B,D:D),A:A=3475,"")
```

How can I get this working? I want to get the filtered result where any value in column A equals 3475, and only get columns A,B and D

Comment: Then you have to write two formula. One is to get column A and B. Another one for column D.

Comment: Why do the columns you don't want bother you?

Comment: How do you want the result? The concatenation of A, B, and D? Or three separate columns?

Comment: @Variatus Because I use the filtered result to create an export file to another platform and only specific columns are required.

Comment: @BigBen 3 separate columns

Answer (score 1):

You could use a single one formula like:

```
=TRANSPOSE(CHOOSE({1,2,3},FILTER(A:A,A:A=3475),TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B:B,A:A=3475)),TRANSPOSE(FILTER(D:D,A1:A4=3475))))
```

But considering performance, I'd go with two seperate formulas as proposed in the comments.

Comment: Thanks. This transposed the columns the wrong way and had errors come up since the results mix up when they transpose vertically. I got rid of all the `TRANSPOSE` and the formula worked perfectly when written as `=CHOOSE({1,2,3},FILTER(A:A,A:A=3475),FILTER(B:B,A:A=3475),FILTER(D:D,A1:A4=3475))`

Answer (score 1):

You need use the proper array for the array argument to the filter function.

I used a Table since using whole-column references is inefficient.

For example, if you want to return only columns 1,2 and 4 of a table, you can use:

```
=INDEX(Table1,SEQUENCE(ROWS(Table1)),{1,2,4})
```

So your filter function might be:

```
=FILTER(INDEX(Table1,SEQUENCE(ROWS(Table1)),{1,2,4}),Table1[colA] = myVar)
```

[image]

IF, for some reason you don't want to use **Tables**, the following formula should also work:

```
=FILTER(INDEX($A:$D,SEQUENCE(LOOKUP(2,1/(LEN($A:$A)>0),ROW($A:$A))),{1,2,4}),myVar=INDEX($A:$A,SEQUENCE(LOOKUP(2,1/(LEN($A:$A)>0),ROW($A:$A)))))
```

as would, the less efficient:

```
=FILTER(INDEX($A:$D,SEQUENCE(ROWS($A:$A)),{1,2,4}),myVar=$A:$A)
```

Comment: Thanks. I wont be using tables so i tried the last one `=FILTER(INDEX($A:$D,SEQUENCE(ROWS($A:$A)),{1,2,4}),myVar=$A:$A)`. I got an error `#NAME?` not sure why. I have used a variant of JvdV's answer as its more simpler

Comment: @West In the formula you used, you probably didn't define `myVar`.